# Get Date, Month and Year separately in HTML

Tags: html, web

I'm new to html. I'm asking about input type of date month and year as the title. I want to get date, month and year separately from each other like this:
Date: (a drop down list for date) Month: (a drop down list for month) Year: (a drop down list for year). 
Thank you!

Comment: Are there something wrong with my question? Why you downvote it ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Okay I will fix it next time :D Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code:

```js
var s,
      DateWidget = {
        settings: {
          months: ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec'],
          day: new Date().getUTCDate(),
          currMonth: new Date().getUTCMonth(),
          currYear: new Date().getUTCFullYear(),
          yearOffset: 21,
          containers: $(".dateDropdown")
        },

        init: function() {
          s = this.settings;
          DW = this;
          s.containers.each(function(){
            DW.removeFallback(this);
            DW.createSelects(this);
            DW.populateSelects(this);
            DW.initializeSelects(this);
            DW.bindUIActions();
          })
        },

        getDaysInMonth: function(month, year) {
           return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
        },

        addDays: function(daySelect, numDays){
          $(daySelect).empty();

          for(var i = 0; i < numDays; i++){
            $("<option />")
              .text(i + 1)
              .val(i + 1)
              .appendTo(daySelect);
          }
        },

        addMonths: function(monthSelect){
          for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++){
            $("<option />")
              .text(s.months[i])
              .val(s.months[i])
              .appendTo(monthSelect);
          }
        },

        addYears: function(yearSelect){
          for(var i = 0; i < s.yearOffset; i++){
            $("<option />")
              .text(i + s.currYear)
              .val(i + s.currYear)
              .appendTo(yearSelect);
          }
        },

        removeFallback: function(container) {
          $(container).empty();
        },

        createSelects: function(container) {
          $("<select class='day'>").appendTo(container);
          $("<select class='month'>").appendTo(container);
          $("<select class='year'>").appendTo(container);
        },

        populateSelects: function(container) {
          DW.addDays($(container).find('.day'), DW.getDaysInMonth(s.currMonth, s.currYear));
          DW.addMonths($(container).find('.month'));
          DW.addYears($(container).find('.year'));
        },

        initializeSelects: function(container) {
          $(container).find('.day').val(s.day);
          $(container).find('.currMonth').val(s.month);
          $(container).find('.currYear').val(s.year);
        },

        bindUIActions: function() {
          $(".month").on("change", function(){
            var daySelect = $(this).prev(), 
                yearSelect = $(this).next(),
                month = s.months.indexOf($(this).val()) + 1,
                days = DW.getDaysInMonth(month, yearSelect.val());
            DW.addDays(daySelect, days);
          });

          $(".year").on("change", function(){
            var daySelect = $(this).prev().prev(), 
                monthSelect = $(this).prev(),
                month = s.months.indexOf(monthSelect.val()) + 1,
                days = DW.getDaysInMonth(month, $(this).val());
            DW.addDays(daySelect, days);
          });
        }
      };

      DateWidget.init();
```

```css
div{ margin:15px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dateDropdown">
      <label for="dateField1">Please enter the date:</label>
      <input id="dateField1" type="text" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy"/>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop down menus can be created using the select element

```
 <select name="day">
  <option value="1">01</option>
  <option value="2">02</option>
   .
   .
  <option value="31">31</option>
</select>
```

([Source](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp))

Note that different months have different number of days, so you might end up specifying invalid dates, like February 30th.

Comment: Yeah yeah... I thought of that. Can we somehow check if it a valid date or something?

Comment: If there is no better suited input type in the HTML version you want to use and is supported by your browser you have to add some extra logic by yourself. Either within the browser using JavaScript (e.g. greying out the submit button during a data change event generated by the select element: if the date is invalid or: activating it if the date is valid) or on the server side (rejecting the input, if it is invalid and displaying a notice).

Answer (score 1):

it is not easy to get date like that by pure html.

Because what is the numbers of drop down list of dayinput depending on monthinput.

you can try html5 date input control  like this:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>hey</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            'use strict';

            function getMyDate() {
                var dateInput = document.getElementById('date');
                var myDate = dateInput.value;
                var myDateArray = myDate.split('-');
                var year = myDateArray[0];
                var month = myDateArray[1];
                var day = myDateArray[2];

                alert(year)
                alert(month)
                alert(day)
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="date" id="date"/>
    <input type="button" value="clickme" onclick="getMyDate()"></body>
    </body>
    </html>
```